# Minio-backed Docker Registry in Kubernetes using self-signed cert for Minio - x509 error

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-registry, minio

I am trying to setup a Docker registry server in Kubernetes with Minio as the storage backend, where Minio used self-signed certificate for TLS. I am pushing my images from a client docker instance connected to a Docker-in-Docker container.
(client -> d-in-d -> registry -> minio)

When I try to initiate a push, the registry registers an `x509: : certificate signed by unknown authority` error.

I tried:

1. Put the CA bundle (the standard Kubernetes CA bundle) used by Minio into every container (registry, d-in-d, and client), run `update-ca-certificates`.
2. Concatenate the CA bundle with the registry's certificate and put the file in `etc/docker/certs.d/REGISTRY_DOMAIN/`. (https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/426)
3. Set the environment variable `AWS_CA_BUNDLE` in the registry deployment. This, in my opinion, would fix the issue, but the AWS SDK does not allow to override settings after creating a session. The next step would be to modify the registry source to load this env var.

None of these attempts worked. Is there something I'm overlooking?